# Java: Certain coordinates labeled on a plotted line

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm working on a program that creates a plotted line from a generated array list of real time numbers. The numbers aren't necessarily linear and can create a crooked pattern. The program counts the points of inversion and gives them to the user, however the clutter on the screen can be quite a problem when a large number of inversions exist. Is there a way to rewrite/modify the code as to make it so that only certain numbers are printed, for example if the person wants the numbers 80, 90, and 143 to only show. Code attached:

---

CustomCoordinate is a custom class that helps setup the list, included for clarity.

```
private int count;
private int num;

public CustomCoordinate(long time, double value, int number) {
    super(time, value);
    this.count = number;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
```

---

For clarification, *selDateInSec* is a calendar object where the user inputs the date of when the first data point label will be located along the x-axis. Any inversion before this won't be labeled, any after will.

```
int x = 0;
if (inversions) {
    for(CustomCoordinate c : points) {
        if(c.getTime() > selDateInSec) {
            Label lbl = new Label (instr.format(++x), f, txtColor, bgColor);
            lbl.setLocation(c);
            addFigure(lbl);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your problem but if you want to only print given numbers why not just check and print if you encounter any of those? If it's a visual problem you might want to calculate the approximate size of those labels (calculating the real size can be a complex task but an approximation should be sufficient) and then only add labels if they're far enough apart from each other.

Comment: I tried doing an "if number is this, print number" solution but it would seriously malfunction when paired with the date functionality. When it is done without a starting date, it works fine but the data output isn't really useful in that context. I'll see what I can do about the labels issue, thank you for the suggestion, although that is my secondary issue.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your issue. What's the problem with combining a check for the date (if needed) and the number?

Comment: The problem is that when the check for the date is used, the label appears over a point that is not correct. I get a label of 50 on the 37th point, for example. I've tried to see if a pattern emerges, if it's always labeled a certain number of points backwards or forwards but to no avail. If I don't use the date functionality, the 50th point is labeled '50'. Furthermore, a different section of code that I've used the date feature on works perfectly fine, so I know that the problem isn't in the date feature itself.

Comment: Hmm, what about calculating the offset that results from date filtering? So if due to the date filter you're starting at point 23 then the 27th rendered point should get label 50 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can take input from the user about the points they are interested in and then use `filter` function on it to filter out the points of interest. Hence you'll be able to show only the points of interest without clutter.